# Trouble understanding solution to exercise

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given: Right tetrahedron, find $\angle \alpha$, between 
surrounding edge(not sure if this is the right term in English, but those edges is AD, BD and CD). and the plane of the base, and $\angle \beta$ between apothem and the base. Here is drawing:
[image]

And here is the presented solution:

Let the point H pass through the middle of AB(AH = BH), and point O is orthogonal projection of D in the base. Now $\angle \alpha = \angle AOD$. Then if we name the length of the edges with $a$, we will obtain that $OA= \frac{a\sqrt{3}}{3}$ , because AO is radius of circumcircle around $\triangle ABC$.I won't finish the solution. Since the thing I can't understand is why $OA= \frac{a\sqrt{3}}{3}$ I mean how did they got it. Also from where does he know that OA is the radius of circumcircle.

Comment: A right tetrahedron has all sides length $a$. A circle through A, B and C has radius $OC = OA=OB = r$. Use the cosine rule to find r in triangle AOC.

Comment: Well in $\triangle AOC$ all I know is that AC = a, and that AO = CO = x so the cosine law will look like $a^2 = x^2 + x^2 - 2*x*x* cos\varphi$, but I don't see how he got $\frac{a \sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: Solve for x then find the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance from a vertex to the center of an equilateral triangle is $2/3$ of the altitude of the triangle. If the side is $a$, the altitude is $(\sqrt3/2)a$. So...